# How to write the equation in polar coordinates

Tags: polar-coordinates

I have the equation $(x-3)^2+y^2=9$ which is a circle centered at 3 and I need to find the polar coordinates for this equation, but I am not sure where to start because the $(x-3)$ is throwing me off. Can I start doing $(r\cos(\theta)-3)^2+r\sin(\theta)^2=9$? Where do I go from there? I am pretty thrown off, but I do know that $r^2 = x^2+y^2$. How could I get it in that form? Once there how would I find $\theta$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may write $(x-3)^2+y^2=9$ as
$$
\begin{align}
(r \cos \theta-3)^2+(r \sin \theta)^2&=9
\\\\
r^2 \cos^2 \theta+r^2 \sin^2 \theta-6r \cos \theta+9&=9
\\\\
r^2 (\cos^2 \theta+\sin^2 \theta)-6r \cos \theta&=0
\\\\
\cos \theta&=\frac{r}6.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Awesome! Once I get there would r just then equal $6cos(\theta)$ and how would I find $\theta$ by itself?

Answer (score 0):

$ \theta = \cos^ {-1} (r/6), r =0.  $  It is a circle through center, centered on x-axis, diameter 6.

Comment: How would $r=0$ if $r$ is just the radius (right?) and the radius being 3?

Comment: How do you get $r=0$, since $r$ will vary?

Comment: @RoryDaulton I don't think $r$ will vary since it is a circle with a constant radius, but I still don't see how it would be 0 because then there would be no circle at all right?

Comment: @RyanGray: Here, $r$ is not the radius of the circle graph, but rather the (signed) distance of any given point on the graph to the origin. Therefore, it differs for each point on the graph.

Comment: @RyanGray :There are *two* roots to the equation OP gave, so should be mentioned in reply. Just as if he would ask roots of $ r^2 - 6 r =0 $, we ought to reply $ r=0,6 $ even if the first one  is trivial, Right?